A war over Taiwan would entail many risks for Russia

A war over Taiwan would entail many risks for Russia:
(source)

Is for Russia adjectival or adverbial?
A friend of mine asked me whether the sentence can be rephrased as "For Russia, a war over Taiwan would entail many risks". Her question is understandable to me, because in sentences like "There are serious risks for XXX" and "That carries many risks for XXX", "for XXX" is usually translated adverbially into Japanese. That said, I think for Russia is adjectival.

I'm not convinced "adjective" and "adverb" are useful categories here, where for Russia is a "prepositional phrase". But it modifies the noun risks, so if that's what you're thinking about, maybe you might want it classify it as adjectival (it doesn't adverbially modify the verb entails, if that's what you were thinking).

for Russia is a prepositional phrase, a supplement in  clause structure, specifying the country  at risk.  It is neither adjectival nor adverbial.
All of these variants are grammatical:

For Russia a war over Taiwan would entail many risks.
A  war over Taiwan would entail many risks for Russia.
A war over Taiwan would entail for Russia a boatload of risk.
A war over Taiwan, for Russia, would entail many risks.

A synthetic language might translate that phrase by putting "Russia" in the dative case, and if the grammarians of the language don't use the term "dative", in an "oblique" or indirect-objective case.
